# Export data of points and polygons which are intersected

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have a shp file of roughly 100 Polygon. I also have a corresponding list (including X,Y data) of about 3000 points, in a csv file. Overlayed within QGis the 100 polygons contain about 90% of the points. I would like to  export the data of the points and polygons which are intersected into a flat file.

Data Description:

```
points 
 - X
 - Y
 - Point Name

Geometry
 - Geometry Data
 - Geometry Name

Output (for all point which are contained within a polygon)
 - Point Name
 - Geometry Name
```

Comment: So you want the points that intersect the geometry layer and you want those points to have the geometry schema info (data/name)?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Does your list of points is in the form of a shp file? i.e. (/or) does it include spatial information?
And is the geometry layer is polygonal?

Comment: the points file is a csv file in the form above and the Geometry is indeed polygonal

Comment: Answer is on the way - basically you should import the X,Y point layer to form a shp file - pay attention to use same coordinate system as the polygons layer. Than you can use join attributes by location (spatial join) to form a relationship between the to tables and geometries. Finally export the joint table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps that you should perform:

- Import your X,Y point data using same coordinate system as defined for your polygons layer.
- Use "join attribute by location" in the vector>data management menu to connect the points layer to the polygons layer. See tutorial - you should do the same [Spatial Join](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php)
- Export the joint table and you've finished. I had attached a printscreen of the result below. The id column is for the points layer and id2 belongs to the polygon. The join will merge all fields and attributes in your tables, so names, points X,Y, and other data will be displayed respectively.

Good Luck

[image]